# Creating two columns layout - html/css semantics

Tags: css, html, semantics

I want to create a very simple liquid layout with 2 columns - the one to the left will have a fixed width, and the one to the right will be dependent to the window size.

The layout will contain 4 elements - the header, navigation, content, and the footer.

I have a couple of questions according to the semantics of HTML5 elements here.

This is the code:

```
<body>
   <div id="container">
       <header>
          <div id="header">
             sadfsdf
          </div>
       </header>
       <nav>
          <div id="nav">
             gdfsgf
          </div>
       </nav>
       <article>
          <div id="article">
             gdffgdg
          </div>
       </article>
       <footer>
          <div id="footer">
             gdfsgf
          </div>   
       </footer>
   </div>
</body>
```

1) Is container div really necessery? What I do is:
HTML has font/lineheight properties
BODY has some margins and background images
CONTAINER contains the rest

Is it O.K. to put body stuff inside of html, and make body the container?

2) Are inner div's in header, nav, ... necessary? They are in there because I can then change padding, margins and borders without changing the width of the element. Should I rather set this width along with every changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) If the container div is needed or not depends very much on your actual design, but from what I can see from what you have showed, it is not really necessary. What is body stuff?

2) You have answered your question yourself. If you want to prevent an overflow because of padding, margin,border, keep it.

Comment: Div#container is only for centering in the middle of the website if max-width is reached. That's why I've thought of letting the body do that. Will this affect anything? (also if I will add any fixed width to it).

And according to the 2)...Is there any semantic HTML5 element for these inner divs? Maybe sections? Or aria roles?

Comment: for centering you don't need the container. you can set the width of html to 100% and then set the max-width of the body to whatever you want, the width to 100% and center the body. To my knowledge, there are no special semantic elements in HTML5 for inner divs.

Answer (score 2):

The best method to have two/more columns in a layout is:

- float the N-1 of columns
- set margin to the other one

**HTML**

```
<div id="left">LEFT</div>
<div id="right">RIGHT</div>
​
```

**CSS**

```
div#left{
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    min-height: 400px;
    background-color: magenta;
}
div#right{
    margin-left: 210px;
    min-height: 400px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
​
```

take a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YGQLF/1/)

EDIT:

- body is the High-level container which contains all the element is passed to the view. sometimes we need to position or form our whole elements in the page, without changing the position of each one comparing to each others. so being an element called container could be useful.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I asked for.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you can use your body as your container.
2. You can get rid of your inner div-s as long as you use `box-sizing: border-box;` More about that here: http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Comment: use box-sizing only when you don't need to support IE 6 and 7

Comment: @SvenBieder you can see that he already used HTML 5 tags, whom are not supported by older IE without a plugin. And for IE 6 & 7 you can always use Google Chrome Frame

Comment: Yes you are right, haven't thought about that he uses HTML5 so or so.

Comment: As far as I know there are libraries allowing HTML5 tags to work in IE6/7.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can look into is using Scaffolding.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html
This is from the fluid layout section. While it does not use a fixed span you could use nested containers.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span2">
      <!--Sidebar content-->
    </div>
    <div class="span10">
      <!--Body content-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```