# Creating CSS columns

Tags: css, html, positioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating two columns layout - html/css semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12914570/creating-two-columns-layout-html-css-semantics)

I have a div that spans the entire browser and another div centered inside that using the code below:

```
.wrapper {width: 1024px; margin: 0 auto; clear: both;}
```

How do I create two column's within the wrapper?

Comment: Note that `width: 1024px` != "the entire browser". On most laptops, this will produce horizontal scrollbars once vertical scrollbars appear. On larger screens, this will create vertical stripes around the page. With fixed layout, anything is easy with absolute postitioning and even without it.

Comment: I actually would like to create something very similar to your site Kevin. Where there are bands of color that span the whole browser and the content centers inside the bands.

Comment: Every time I float the div it jumps out of the color band.

Answer (score 1):

use floats (and clear them) or use `display:inline-blocks`.

Here, I made you a [colorful example](http://jsfiddle.net/c37p8/).

html

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="col1">a</div>
    <div id="col2">b</div>    
    <br style="clear:both" />
</div>

<hr />

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="col">a</div>
    <div class="col">b</div>   
</div>
```

css

```
body {background:blue;}
.wrapper {width: 80%; margin:0px auto; background:red;height:300px;}

#col1 {width:50%;float:left;background:green; height:200px;}
#col2 {width:50%;float:right;height:200px;background:lightblue;}

.col {display:inline-block; width:49%;height:200px;background:pink;}
```